# Execute custom MSBuild task always after build process

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, msbuild-task

I created a custom Task that executes after the build operation.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" />
<Target Name="MyTarget"
        AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
  <MyTask ... />
</Target>
```

**QUESTION**: Is it possible to execute the task, if the build operation was triggered, but did not perform, because there are no changes in the project / no need to build again?

In other words: I want to execute the task always at the end of the build process, even if the project was not built again.

**UPDATE**: Using `AfterTargets="Build"` <strike>or setting the property `<DisableFastUpToDateCheck>true</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>`</strike> does not help.

After triggering the Build process a second time, I only get the Output: `Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped`

Comment: How did you trigger the Build process a second time? Just click build in Visual Studio?

Comment: @Leo-MSFT Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to execute the task, if the build operation was triggered, but did not perform, because there are no changes in the project / no need to build again?

If I understand you correctly, you can define this property in your project file:

```
<PropertyGroup> 
  <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>true</DisableFastUpToDateCheck> 
</PropertyGroup>
```

Note: This method seems that Visual Studio is bypassing normal up-to-date checks of MSBuild and using some sort of custom check that is faster, but has a side effect of breaking customized build targets.

Update:
Not sure the reason why this method not work on your project, let me make the answer more detail:

1. Define the property in your project file:
2. Add the custom MSBuild task with some messages info.
3. Build the project, check the output(log file verbosity is Normal).
4. Build the project again, check the output again.

Comment: MSBuild cmd is no option. Defining the property did not help.

Comment: @ChristianSt., thanks for you reply. I test it on my macine, it works fine. Not sure the reason why it not work for you project. You can try to create a new blank project and follow my steps to verify this issue, check if it works fine. If not, could please share us the project type and other info, or share us a sample to us so that we could reproduce this issue.

Comment: Aaaahhh sorry... setting the property IS the solution. My fault was that I did not set the property directly in the project file. Instead I set it in a project file that is shared (Import ....)) between multiple projects. It is working now. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I use `AfterTargets="Build"` instead of `AfterBuild`, the message is written to the Output window every time I build the solution (.NET Core Console App with a .NET Standard Class Libary).

```
  <Target Name="MyAfterBuild" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Hello World!" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Can not reproduce that. I only get (as before) the output `Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped`